# How to save features into .mat file and .txt file using python in keras?

Tags: matlab, python-2.7, keras, keras-2

I would like to save my predicted features into .mat format and .txt format in keras for further process in Matlab. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For .mat, check out [SciPy's File IO](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html).

For .txt, there are many options, such as [NumPy's `savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).

Check out the [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) format as well, which is a common way to save data for cross-platform use.